# Catching a system call just before control enters a shared library

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have wrapped a number of system call function like write(), open() etc and LD-PRELOAD is used to override the original system calls. Moreover I have defined a few more functions and made this too a shred library.

I would like to catch all system calls from different application processes to these shared libraries before they enter the shared library. How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: System calls are wone thing, library calls are another. You may want to look at the source code of `strace` amd `ltrace` tools.

Comment: @n.m. a helpfull pointer. din't think of it

Comment: You are mixing up stuff: the correspondence between system calls and documented API entry points (open, close, etc.) is not 1:1.

Answer (score 5):

LD_PRELOAD is not necessarily a good way to interpose system calls, because a) it only allows you to intercept library calls and b) it only allows you to intercept library calls. ;)

A) While in general, system calls are wrapped by the shared libC in your system, no one prevents you from calling a system call yourself, e.g., but setting up the right register content and then issuing INT 0x80 on an x86 system. If the program you're interested in does so, you'll never catch those with LD_PRELOAD-based libc-interposition.

B) While in general, most programs use the shared libC in your system to make system calls, sometimes applications are linked statically, which means the libC code is part of the application and does not come from the shared lib. In such cases, LD_PRELOAD also does not help.

A comment already suggested to use strace/ltrace -- my generalized advice would be to have a look at ptrace() which both of these tools use and which should give you what you want without the need of modifying the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

[Patch-free User-level Link-time intercepting of system calls and interposing on library functions](http://okmij.org/ftp/syscall-interpose.html) may do the trick but I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the only way you can do this is by modifying the system call table. HIDS systems (such as Samhain) will report this as an intrusion and Linux kernel developers frown upon this, heavily. The implementation details are very specific to the OS (i.e. what works on FreeBSD won't necessarily work on Linux), but the general implementation details are going to be the same. A kernel module might be a better way to go with cleaner, more standardized APIs.